# Pause a test in codeception (when using the selenium webdriver)

Tags: selenium, codeception

Is there a way to pause and then resume codeception test execution with a statement in the test code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, use pauseExecution method in WebDriver module, and run codeception with the "--debug" flag.